Chart Indicator: Why Does RSI (14, close) Vary with the Particular Time Chart I am Using?
This is probably an easy question for many of you: If I am viewing a Month chart and plot the RSI 14, it tells me the current day's RSI, which I think is the RSI of the last 14 days. But why, if I change from the 1 week chart to, say, the 1 year chart, does the RSI 14 for the current day change? I had thought that even though the time is more 'stretched out' or smooth for the 1 year chart vs. the 1 week chart, the calculation of the past 14 days' RSI should be the same. Wnere am I off with my thinking? Thanks in advance!

If the frequency of your datapoints change, the RSI changes becuase the last 14 datapoints measured from that timepoint have changed. If only the scale of the chart changes and the RSI still references the same 14 last days datapoints (even if they are not individually visible) then the RSI as described should not change.

Thanks, Are you saying it's possible that, with some software, the '14' in "RSI 14' stands for, for example, months and not days if I switch the scale from Day to Month?

What tool do you use? Frequently, computer code will just take any array and not care about the periodicity. A simple python dummy code: [np.log(price[i]/price[i+1]) for i in range(0,13)], where price is an array of prices, which can be daily, weekly, monthly, yearly or anything else really.

Thanks for replying. To answer your question, I am using charts on my Robinhood account. It asks me to specify the number of days when I choose RSI, so I choose 14.
